# How to put new page into a frame thats inside main html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to put a graph that can be interactable with main page onto the canvas. ive seen many pages that use this: ["#document" being used inside frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYj1C.png)

im not sure how to connect everything together. could someone teach me how to do this?
thanks :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe here you are

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily reach your purpose by use `iframe`:

```html
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
</iframe>
```

See more: [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)